# How do I only keep files in a directory that contain a specific string?

Tags: python, os.walk

I am trying to open all the HTML files in a directory, read the HTML files, and only keep the HTML files that contain the phrase "apples and oranges."

I tried opening every file in the directory, then applying the BeautifulSoup function on it.

```
import os
import fnmatch
from pathlib import Path
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

directory = "/directorypath"

for dirpath, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, '*.html'):
        with open(os.path.join(dirpath, filename)):
            soup = BeautifulSoup(files, 'html.parser')
            print(soup.prettify())
            soup.find_all('apples and oranges')
        filename.close()
```

My expected result is to only see files in the directory that contains the phrase "apples and oranges."

The error message says:

```
  File "soupy4.py", line 14, in <module>
    filename.close()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'close'
marshiehmacbook:board marcyshieh$ python3 soupy4.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "soupy4.py", line 11, in <module>
    soup = BeautifulSoup(files, 'html.parser')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bs4/__init__.py", line 300, in __init__
    markup, from_encoding, exclude_encodings=exclude_encodings)):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bs4/builder/_htmlparser.py", line 240, in prepare_markup
    exclude_encodings=exclude_encodings)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bs4/dammit.py", line 374, in __init__
    for encoding in self.detector.encodings:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bs4/dammit.py", line 265, in encodings
    self.markup, self.is_html)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bs4/dammit.py", line 323, in find_declared_encoding
    declared_encoding_match = xml_encoding_re.search(markup, endpos=xml_endpos)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Comment: Please provide the whole Traceback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I belive the issue is you aren't actually reading in the file. In `soup = BeautifulSoup(files, 'html.parser')`, `files` is not an string.

You need to read that in first, then pass that into BeautifulSoup:

```
import os
import fnmatch
from pathlib import Path
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

directory = "/directorypath"

for dirpath, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, '*.html'):
        with open(os.path.join(dirpath, filename)) as f:
            html = f.read()
            soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
            print(soup.prettify())
            soup.find_all('apples and oranges')
```

And actually, if all you're doing is checking to see if that phrase is in the file, you don't need BeautfulSoup. Just once you read it in, see if it's within the text:

```
import os
import fnmatch

directory = "/directorypath"

remove_files = []

for dirpath, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, '*.html'):
        with open(os.path.join(dirpath, filename)) as f:
            html = f.read()
            if 'apples and oranges' in html:
                print ('Found apples and oranges.')
            else:
                remove_files.append(os.path.join(dirpath, filename))

for each in remove_files:
    os.remove(each)
    print ('REMOVED: %s' %each)
```

Comment: Thank you for this. How do I remove the files that do not contain "apples and oranges" and only keep the files that do?

Comment: just include that in your if statement. I updated above. Be sure to accept the solution if it met your needs

Comment: I am having a different error when I loop through the entire directory: ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "soupy4.py", line 14, in <module>
    html = f.read()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x93 in position 537: invalid start byte```

Comment: try changing to this: `with open(os.path.join(dirpath, filename), 'rb') as f:` If that doesn't work, try `with open(os.path.join(dirpath, filename), errors='ignore') as f:`